# Why does setting a PropertyChangedEventHandler on the Desktop not work when TreeScope_Children is used?

Tags: visual-c++, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm working in C++ using Microsoft's UIAutomation framework.  I have a need to be notified when any top-level windows on the desktop have their title changed.
In my understanding, I should just be able to register a PropertyChangedEventHandler on the desktop to watch for UIA_NamePropertyID changes.  The scope of that handler should be TreeScope_Children, because I don't care about the lower levels of the windows.

The code should look like this:

```
IUIAutomationPropertyChangedEventHandler* eHandler = <create a handler>;
IUIAutomationElement* deskTopElement = <retrieve the desktop element>;
CComSafeArray<PROPERTYID> propArray(1);
propArray[0] = UIA_NamePropertyId;

uiaInterface->AddPropertyChangedEventHandler(deskTopElement, TreeScope_Children, NULL, eHandler, propArray);
```

I get an HRESULT of S_OK, and things look all right.  However, I never get any events.

If I change the scope to TreeScope_Descendants, then I start getting all the desired events, those of the top-level window title changes, but also ALL the lower-level ones.  This means, to me, that I'm setting the event handler up correctly, it's just unable to process the TreeScope_Children scope correctly.

I'm rather confused about this, because if I use AccEvent.exe to look for those events, it works as I expect:  I select Desktop as the entity, and "Immediate children" from which to include events.  I select the Name PropertyID and let it go to town.  I get all the events I expect, and none of what I don't want.

So, does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Note that I can work around this by gathering all the immediate children of the desktop, then setting a similar handler on each of them with scope TreeScope_Element, then watching for new windows and setting a handler on each new one.  But that seems rather overkill for such a (seemingly) simple task.

Comment: Handlers are more or less per automation element. You must first get a reference on each item (window here) you're interested in, and then add a property change handler on each of these items. You cannot set a global handler for "everything in the desktop", because an automation tree is 1) huge and 2) never fully known in the depths as it's related to other apps behavior with regard to end-user manipulations

Comment: Seems like there's a disconnect here.  In the case I'm working on, I can certainly set an event handler on the desktop, with TreeScope_Descendants, and I get notified as expected.  So it's definitely not necessary to get all the elements and set an event handler on them.  And, as I wrote, I CAN set a global handler for everything in the desktop with a scope of TreeScope_Descendants and get notified of all changes.
Maybe you're thinking of some other automation system?

Comment: Note sure what's your problem. This code (C# but it's the same) seems to work fine: https://pastebin.com/raw/dC938AZ7